# AWS issue: the requested URL was not found on this server

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

This is the first time I use AWS and I successfully created an instance:

[image]

The instance is to host a wordpress installation, I installed wordpress through PuTTY and modified the config file.

[image]
The AWS instance is running but why there are the following issues:
1. When I typed in the IP (an elastical IP) which associated with the wordpress instance, the browser gives me error:

the requested URL was not found on this server.
[image]

2. How do I FTP into the server?

Comment: It is a problem with your Apache config can you paste your Apache host file for that website? And you cannot FTP in EC2 right away you have to set that up. Use SFTP instead of FTP or Ssh from command line.

Comment: Thank you for your quick attention, this is my first time using AWS, can you tell me where can i find the apache host file? Normally I host my websites on company like Bluehost and use FileZilla to get in the backend

Comment: Your question is very broad to answer check this guide https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/hosting-wordpress.html and follow that exact steps for installing wordpress on AWS EC2 instance as from the screenshot I believe you pasted the Wordpress files under the EC2-USER directory which is not correct

Comment: FileZilla supports SFTP, so you can continue to use that.

Comment: @error2007s: thanks for indicating the directory problem, I've moved the wordpress to /home, and it still gives me the same error

Comment: @MarkB: Thanks. Can you advise how to set up the FTP access?

Comment: @mdivk as I said, it is SFTP, not FTP. And it is the same info you use to connect via SSH. You would use the user account `ec2-user` and the SSH key to login via SFTP. You won't need to make any changes to the server in order for this to work.

Comment: Thanks Mark for clarifying again for the SFTP, I am now able to use FileZilla to access the server now, however, I am suspecting there are some other issues as the error says `The requested URL /myblog was not found on this server.`

Comment: I figured out the issue: all I need to do is to move the completed wp folder to /var/www/html as that is where the site sits in. There are still issues on installing theme though, but that's beyond this question's scope, thank you for watching and replying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue: all I need to do is to move the completed wp folder to /var/www/html as that is where the site sits in. There are still issues on installing theme though, but that's beyond this question's scope, thank you for watching and replying.

Comment: this won't work and I don't think this is the right answer.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to allow AllowOverride

```
sudo vim /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
```

Find the section that starts with .

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">
    #
    # Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
    # or any combination of:
    #   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
    #
    # Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
    # doesn't give it to you.
    #
    # The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
    # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#options
    # for more information.
    #
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

    #
    # AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
    # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
    #   Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
    #
    AllowOverride None

    #
    # Controls who can get stuff from this server.
    #
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Change the AllowOverride None line in the above section to read AllowOverride All.
..
and restart server

```
sudo reboot
```

Now login again and Don't forget to start mariadb again if you have installed.

```
sudo systemctl start mariadb
```

---

I know I'm answering it too late but that was my question too some time ago when I started with aws 1st time

Answer (score 0):

edit public/.htaccess and change:

Eg: `vi /var/www/html/yourprojdir/.htaccess`

```
# if in web root
# RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

# if in subdir comment above line, uncomment below one and replace <OSPOS path> with your path
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /opensourcepos/public/index.php?/$1 [L]

sudo a2enmod rewrite

sudo systemctrl restart apache2
```

Comment: the request URL is  http://ipaddress/subfolder/login/validate .  But response received at different URL  http://ipaddress/subfolder/login with Status Code: 303 See Other

Answer (score 0):

Open your virtual host file, example:

```
sudo vim /etc/httpd/conf.d/mysite.conf
```

Your '<Directory "/var/www/html">' needs to look like this:

```
<Directory /var/www/html>
  Options FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride All
  Order Allow,Deny
  Allow from all
</Directory>
```